# Saving a file with current date & time for the file name Winform C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I've made it possible to save a file from my winform using the Vlcdotnet framework. At the moment this code is as follows:

```
 _tempVLCWindow.TakeSnapshot("C:\\ScreenCap.jpg", 1280, 720);
```

Now, instead of "ScreenCap" being the file (which only allows me to save one single image) I want it to store the current date & time so I can save multiple snapshots. How is this possible?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) Have you looked into the documentation, searching for some relevant keywords, such as *date* or *time*? If so, what has this search brought up, and what exactly did not work out when you tried to apply that knowledge yourself?

Comment: At the moment this question does not make sense. What do you mean by 'I want it to store the current date & time so I can save multiple snapshots'?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx, it should help you come across the solution yourself.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx you should take a look at reference page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can do following:

```
String fileName = "C:\\ScreenCap_" +  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".jpg";
_tempVLCWindow.TakeSnapshot(fileName , 1280, 720);
```

This will create you a filename like: C:\ScreenCap_20130307_1023.jpg

By calling ToString() and specifying the format as YearMonthDay_HourMinutesSeconds (yyyyMMdd_hhmmss) you will be able to create a string with the date and time that will be accepted as a file name. If you did call only .ToString() you will get an illegal characters in path exception.

For formatting options in *date.tostring("")* look at: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: An explanation rather than an answer for mindless copy-and-pasting would be more helpful to future visitors who have an equivalent, but not the same problem.

Comment: This is better than my suggestion.

Comment: sorry that it took a little delay.. i startet writing my post while no answer was here

Answer (score 0):

If I did not get you wrong you may try this:

```
string filename = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString()+DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();

_tempVLCWindow.TakeSnapshot(String.Format("C:\\{0}.jpg", filename), 1280, 720);
```